# How can i level task by order in MS-project if the first task i set start time

Tags: ms-project

I want to level resource by ID. But when I set the first task start at 8 pm , the second task resource not sequence by task1. If program see available time before task 1 start and resource of task 2 can finish on-time, task 2 will be schedule before task1

How can i set leveling resource by ID if I have to set start time of task 1?